# 6d Mark ii dark image issues

Tags: camera-settings, camera

I just bought a 6d Mark ii and had a photo shoot with a black model and we used a black wall and for some reason his skin was smudgy and today i did some test shot with some natural light on some black joggers and they came out looking blue and soft . Any idea on how i can fix this issue ?? 
[image][image]

Comment: Did you shoot raw or JPEG? Did you color balance to a reference white? Is your monitor calibrated? If you shot JPEG or answered NO to either of the other two questions, all bets are off.  You need a real color workflow to get decent results.  No automatic system in the world can cope with that solid magenta background.

Comment: Yeah i shot  In raw. I went to the camera shop and tad what they pretty much told me. To play with my white balance (since it was in auto) .  I did a shoot outside using the same black guy and had no issues. So I’m guessing it was my exposure?  Since the other times it was in doors.

Answer (score 4):

For the black guy on the black background: your metering will see very little light coming from your scene, so the camera will basically over-expose. The solution here is to use exposure correction (-1 EV to start?), or go manual and use a gray card to determine your exposure.

For the black shorts on a magenta background: on automatic white balance, the camera will try to get an overall neutral colour. It sees that heavy magenta background, with no other colour, so it will push  the colour towards blue/green. Adjusting the colour temperature of your jpeg from 6500K/tint:1 to 7500K/tint:0.98 gets rid of the blue cast. That gives a bit of magenta in the upper right part of the shorts, but that's a normal reflection of the background.

White balance errors aren't much of an issue when shooting raw (as the whitebalance isn't applied to the raw data), shooting jpeg you have to be a lot more careful. So either set a custom white balance on a test target, or set a fixed white balance (depending on your light source). If you are using any kind of led or fluorescent light, the white balance target is the best solution.

Comment: You should probably note that with fluorescent lighting the flicker of the lights will alter WB from one frame to the next unless shutter times slower than the frequency of the lights are used.

Answer (score 2):

I think remco's answer is good. You can also take a little time to preview images during your shoot. That can be easier with tethering to a notebook, but you could simply connect a battery-powered tablet-sized HDMI display with a folding light hood. There are a number available for about $200 that are pretty decent quality and could do wonders for your on-site confidence that you've got the shoot "in the bag". (Examples include the models from Feelworld on Amazon, e.g. [Feelworld F570 5.7" IPS Full HD 1920x1080 On Camera Monitor Support 4K HDMI Input/Output for DSLR Cameras and Gimbal Stabilizer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0768B36BW) )

Look at Datacolor targets, e.g. [Datacolor SCK200 SpyderCHECKR 24](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LPS46TW) and, if you don't already have a display calibrator, you might look at other offerings from the Datacolor, e.g. the [Spyder5Pro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UBSL31Q)

Otherwise, at least avoid using auto color balance if shooting a strange scene (like the shorts on a magenta background). If you shoot in RAW, you can easily adjust the color balance, anyway, but it is always easier to just have it come into Lightroom (or whatever your chosen RAW developer/catalog is), almost ready to go.